# How to check a comma delimited integer values by "IF" condition T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A simple table contains the one column with integer vales.The Figure is given below.

[image: A table named model with one column 'numbers']

I am using COALESCE to construct the 'numbers' by comma.

[image: comma delimited value]

So, now there is a problem when i check a above constructed value in IF Condition like below. It shows an error for cannot convert the varchar datatype to integer.

[image]

Now how to check the constructed values in IF condition without changing a logic? I am new for T-SQL.Thank you

Comment: You can't treat a delimited list of values as a single value. What your code is trying to do is determine if your delimited list contains the integer value 23. That means it has to do an implicit conversion which will not work. You need to use like and strings to do this. It would be better if you don't cram all these values into a single variable and keep the data separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate all the numbers you are converting it a string so it no longer acts like an integer. If you want to check for a value in a list, do it directly like. SQL was made to have different values in different rows and work with them that way. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @failIds INT = 23;

IF @failIds IN (SELECT numbers FROM model)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'YES'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NO'
END
```

Comment: Yes, I just try this... I get the solution... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the comma separated string, you should use a table variable, temp. table or just the original table. For example, something like this:

```
declare @Ids table (id int)

insert into @Ids
select numbers
from model
where numbers in (23,234)

declare @failIds int = 23

if (exists (select 1 from @Ids where id = @failIds)) begin
  print 'Yes'
end else begin
  print 'No'
end
```

But you could of course do this too:

```
if (exists (select 1 from model where numbers = @failIds)) begin
  print 'Yes'
end else begin
  print 'No'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very lazy to think about it, Finally i get answer like give below. Its very simple.

[image]

Comment: IF @failIds IN (23, 234)  would work the same way if this is the actual code you're using.  no need to select the ids from the table if you already know the ids

Comment: Yes i know but the ids are different from above.... the above logic is like example not an exact code from me... thanks